# How can I scale up my django app to utilize 4 cores and 8 threads?

Tags: django, multithreading, scaling, scalability

I have a Django app. I am about to move this from a single core system to a multi core system. (8 threads because of hyperthreading)

I am trying to figure out the changes I need to make to utilize all of the cores and all of the threads. I looked around and found bunch of settings for Rails. I can not find similar settings for Django online.

I found an article that says, I don't need to make any changes to Django. I should just use gunicorn to run 8 instances to utilize 8 threads, but this did not make sense to me.

What do I need to change to make sure my app utilizes 8 threads without wasting resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django itself is a single-threaded web framework, but it can be deployed on multi-core servers to handle multiple requests simultaneously.

You can

1. **use a Web Server**. Django can be deployed on a web server such as `Apache`, `Nginx`, or `Gunicorn`. These web servers can be configured to spawn multiple worker processes or threads to handle incoming requests. Each worker process/thread can handle a single request at a time, and multiple requests can be handled concurrently by multiple workers.
2. **use a WSGI Server**. Django can also be deployed on a WSGI (Web Server Gateway Interface) server such as `uWSGI` or `mod_wsgi`. WSGI servers are specifically designed to handle Python web applications and can spawn multiple worker processes/threads to handle incoming requests.
3. or **use ASGI**. Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface (ASGI) is a standard interface for asynchronous web servers and frameworks in Python. ASGI allows for multiple simultaneous connections to be handled in a non-blocking way. Django 3.0 and later versions support ASGI, and it can be used to deploy Django on an ASGI-compatible web server such as `Daphne` or `uvicorn`.

You could potentially offload some heavy stuff to `Celery`.

Answer (score 1):

> I should just use gunicorn to run 8 instances to utilize 8 threads,
> but this did not make sense to me.

this is the easiest way and it definitely makes sense. You will have multiple instances of your app and load will be balanced. OS will utilize multiple cores to run multiple processes of your app.

Comment: I have run into this exact situation many times in Rails. I refuse to believe something that can be done in 5 minutes in rails can not be done in Django. I heard many Rails developers say bad things about Django but I refuse to believe it is that bad.

If we need to spawn a process to handle more requests, are we not wasting a lot of resources?

Comment: You will need more RAM to have multiple processes running the same code, comparing to a single process. What actual behavior do you have in Rails that you are trying to achieve in Django? Single-process multi-threaded server? Something else? Also a bit strange that you want just to "utilizes 8 threads" do you have some performance problem that you are trying to solve?